# Creating a Stored Procedure to Load data into Dimension table (with conversions)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I need to load a dimension table with data from the source table. I have to convert some columns into different data types. Im not sure how to set up my code properly or deal with some of the syntax errors.

I need to turn the Latitude and Longitude into geography type. I also need to turn the Timezone from text to integer. Heres the code Im working on.

```
USE DBM298_DataMart;
GO

CREATE PROC Load_Dim_Aiports
AS
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Dim_Airports ON

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Dim_Airports

(AirportId, AirportName, City, Country, LatLong , Altitude, Timezone)

SELECT AirportId, AirportName,City,Country, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Timezone

FROM src_flights;
SET LatLong =  geography::Point(Latitude,Longitude,4326)

DECLARE @NegativeNumeric  INT

DECLARE @NegativeCharString VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @NegativeNumeric = -1 * CAST ( REPLACE(@NegativeCharString ,'-','') AS DECIMAL (10,2)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
USE DBM298_DataMart;
GO

CREATE PROC Load_Dim_Aiports
AS
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Dim_Airports ON

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Dim_Airports

(AirportId, AirportName, City, Country, LatLong , Altitude, Timezone)

SELECT AirportId, AirportName, City, Country, geography::Point(Latitude,Longitude,4326) as LatLong , Altitude, cast(Timezone as int) as Timezone 

FROM src_flights;

END
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! I couldnt figure out where the geography part went. You helped me a lot with this one!